# Insert into two tables and affect the id of one of the table columns into the other table

Tags: sql

I have a `Folder` table which contain the following columns:

```
id    | name       | state    | imageFolder                
-------------------------------------------
1        NameTest       1           2
```

And I have another one called `Images` which contains:

```
  id    | url                     
  --------------------------------------------
    2     https://www.someImageUrl
```

I want to insert an url in the folder table in a query and put it in the images and get the id in the same query.

Actually, I am working on an Android project, I have to add a new folder and upload an image to it so that's why I need this.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Can you please rephrase or clarify what you mean by "I want to insert an url in the folder table in a query and put it in the images and get the id in the same query."

Comment: Is id column a identity column ? Do you want to get the identity with which the image was inserted in folder table so that you can use it in images table for making a entry ?

Comment: I have to add a new folder in the folder table which consist of a name, state and and imageID but the image added should be stored into the images table and get its id and put it into the imageID which is at the folder table

Comment: What I understand is that you would insert a record into folder table, and you want imageID that is ID of images table to be inserted automatically for that image. Would you be adding URL also while inserting into folder table ?

Comment: yes that's what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to capture the key value being generated by the `IMAGE` table.  Some people use `@@IDENTITY`, do not do that, it has a global scope and you can *sometimes* get back the wrong ID.

Then use that value to insert into the `FOLDER` table.  It feels a little backwards to insert into the `IMAGE` table first but that's how you get the `ID` you want.  Here is a fully functional example:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('IMAGE') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE [IMAGE]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[IMAGE](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [url] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_IMAGE] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('FOLDER') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE [FOLDER]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FOLDER](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [state] [int] NOT NULL,
    [image_id] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_FOLDER] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

DECLARE @IMAGE_ID INT

INSERT INTO IMAGE(url)
VALUES ('http://www.example.com')

SET @IMAGE_ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()  --This is the key part

INSERT INTO FOLDER(NAME, STATE, IMAGE_ID)
VALUES ('NameTest', 1, @IMAGE_ID)

GO

SELECT * FROM IMAGE
SELECT * FROM FOLDER
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: Happy to help :)